# Is there a way to write multiple pandas dataframes to the same sheet using openpyxl engine?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have done this but only the last dataframe was successfully written in the sheet.
And I also found some samples to achive this using xlsxwriter engine,but how to do with openpyxl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as xlsx:
    df1.to_excel(xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet 1')
    df2.to_excel(xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet 1', startrow=len(df1) + 2)
```

[image]